# How to print result to standard output?

Tags: c

```
            char line[MAXBUF];
            char *result;

            while((result = fgets(line, MAXBUF, fp)) != NULL) {
                printf(result); 
            }
```

The following code doesn't work fully. Does anyone know how to print result?? MAXBUF is defined to be 1024 and fp is just a file pointer to some file. What im suppose to do in this assignment is read file and print the files output to standard output. Any ideas?

On the line printf(result) i get this error "warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments"

Comment: How does it not work, and what do you expect  ? (and incidentally, does the file you read contain any % characters, e.g. %d or.. %s ?)

Comment: One should really use `printf("%s", result)` rather than `printf(result)`, especially if `result` contains `%` characters.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", line);` or `printf("%s", line); fflush(stdout);`

Comment: @JoshD, `line` and `result` should always the same until `result` is `NULL`.  Yes, but that's probably not the main problem, unless the test data actually contains conversions (e.g. a percent sign).  @Azn, what does "doesn't work fully" mean?  What happens?

Comment: @John, `fgets` preserves newlines, so you would expect all but the last line to print even without `fflush`.

Comment: what does %s mean or do in c? and whats the difference between %s\n and %s?. When i mean it doesn't fully work i mean on the line printf(result) i get this error "warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments"

Comment: @Azn, yes, that's the issue @In silico pointed out, and his solution is right.  `%s` is the [`printf`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fprintf.html) specifier meaning a NUL-terminated string.  Adding the `\n` just means it will output an extra newline.

Comment: Sorry im really new to c so NUL-terminated string??

Comment: @Matthew: yes, I was kind of on autopilot there. @KunGor: C doesn't have a string data type as such; instead, strings are represented by sequences of character values terminated by a 0; NUL is the ASCII name for the 0-valued character. IOW, the string "foo" is represented by the character sequence {'f', 'o', 'o', 0}. The `%s` conversion specifier tells `printf` to interpret `line` as a string as defined above and format the output accordingly. The `\n` represents a newline character; `printf("%s\n", line);` means "print the contents of `line` as text followed by a newline".

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down for me. I think i got it now =p

Answer (score 1):

The following is what you want to do:

```
char line[MAXBUF];
char *result;

while((result = fgets(line, MAXBUF, fp)) != NULL) {
      printf("%s", line);
}
```

The fgets inputs the line (retaining the newline).  You are checking result, which is correct.  Theoretically, result should equal line.  The printf doesn't have a '\n' because the newline character is retained from the fgets (see the manpage).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the fgets specification, better:

```
while( fgets(line, MAXBUF, fp)!= NULL) {
                puts(line); 
            }
```

or

```
while( fgets(line, MAXBUF, fp) ) {
                puts(line); 
            }
```

Comment: I don't see what this accomplishes besides adding an extra newline between each line.  `result` may not be necessary, but it's not wrong.